# Webhook doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks, discord, discord.js

I'm not really experienced in Node.js and JavaScript and all that and I wanted to add a webhook to my Discord server.
I found this GitHub project that I'd like to implement: https://github.com/FrankenMan/me_irl-webhook

So I followed the Discord documentation, made a fork, added the webhook, and everything seems to work (I get automatic discord messages everytime I make a commit), however, the bot doesn't do anything.

Here's my fork: https://github.com/Spyder-exe/me_irl-webhook/

So I did a bit of research, and I found that the bot needed a config.json file and a posts.json file. So I renamed the config.json.example and added my webhook's id and token, I created a blank posts.json file.

I also changed the package.json file as the project was a year old from that:

```
"dependencies": {
  "discord.js": "^11.0.0",
  "erlpack": "github:hammerandchisel/erlpack",
  "request": "^2.79.0",
  "uws": "^0.13.0"
}
```

To this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "discord.js": ">=11.0.0",
  "erlpack": "github:discordapp/erlpack",
  "request": ">=2.79.0",
  "uws": ">=0.13.0"
}
```

However the bot still doesn't seem to do anything, here's the main bot.js code, again I'm not that experienced with Javascript so I can't tell what's wrong

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');
const posts = require('./posts.json');

const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(config.webhookid, config.webhooktoken);

const postDict = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./posts.json', 'utf8'));
//function for logging ids and urls of posts to stop repeat posts.
function postLog(postId, postUrl) {
  postDict[postId] = {
    url: postUrl
  };
  fs.writeFile('./posts.json', JSON.stringify(postDict), (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  });
}

function fetchRedditPost() {
  request(config.url, function(error, response, body) {
    var ok = JSON.parse(body);
    ok.data.children.forEach(function(ok) {
      let NUT = "imgur.com";
      let ext = ".jpg";
      let otherExt = ".gif";
      let dril = ".gifv";
      let r34 = ".png";
      let alb = "/a/";
      //checking if it's an imgur link without .jpg, .gif, .gifv, .png
      if (ok.data.url.includes(NUT) && !ok.data.url.includes(ext && otherExt && dril && r34)) {
        const SHACK = ok.data.url + ext;
        //skip imgur album links
        if (ok.data.url.includes(alb)) return;
        //check if this post has been logged. If false, post it on Discord and log it, if true, do not post it
        if (!postDict[ok.data.id]) {
          webhook.sendMessage(`${ok.data.title}\n${SHACK}`);
          postLog(ok.data.id, SHACK);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
      //urls containing i.reddituploads.com don't show up in Discord
      else if (ok.data.url.includes("i.reddituploads.com")) {
        if (!postDict[ok.data.id]) {
          postLog(ok.data.id, ok.data.preview.images[0].source.url);
          webhook.sendMessage(`${ok.data.title}\n${ok.data.preview.images[0].source.url}`);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else {
        if (!postDict[ok.data.id]) {
          postLog(ok.data.id, ok.data.url);
          webhook.sendMessage(`${ok.data.title}\n${ok.data.url}`);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function redditInterval() {
  setInterval(() => (fetchRedditPost()), 36000);
}
redditInterval();
```

Comment: The change to >= is not needed, please try it with the original file.

Comment: First step to debugging would be to figure out if your code is attempting to make any requests or not, just add `console.log` statements before each `webhook.sendMessage` and verify in the console that you're getting some output.

Comment: I've checked your webhook and I saw that it doesn't exist. Maybe you entered a wrong one in GitHub for security.